# Socket would not connect in Python

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I'm having a problem with my code.
The connection should work but the server does not get anything, even though I'm sending data.

Could you check out my code and help me?

```
import socket

def inviare(ip,port):
    file_name = raw_input("File name? ")
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((ip,port))
    file_open = open(file_name,"r")
    file_content = file_open.read()
    print file_content
    sock.send(file_content)
    file_open.close()
    sock.close()

def ricevere(ip,port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((ip,port))
    sock.listen(5)
    while 1:
        (connection, adress) = sock.accept()

        try:
            file_data = sock.recv(6000)
            filewrite = open("Down.txt","w")
            print file_data.read()
            filewrite.write(file_data.readlines())
            filewrite.close
        except:
            pass

def main():
    command = raw_input("Send or receive? ");
    if(command == "receive"):
        ip = raw_input("Ip ")
        port = input("Port ")
        ricevere(ip,port)

    elif(command == "send"):

        ip = raw_input("Ip ?")
        port = input("Port?")
        inviare(ip,port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried to run it in several machines and changed lots of things, but nothing happened. Same problem, but it does not output any error!

Comment: Maybe you want to replace the `pass` in the except-clause with something more verbose, to make sure that nothing bad happens inside the try-block. (Also you don't close the file due to missing parentheses after `close`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `ricevere` you are trying to read from your server socket (`sock`) and not from the connected client `connection`.

Hence it raises: `[Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`

(Which you can see if you don't pass the except-clause, but actually print the exception.)

You script runs as expected, when you change your try-block to:

```
        file_data = connection.recv(6000)
        filewrite = open("Down.txt","w")
        print file_data
        filewrite.write(file_data)
        filewrite.close()
```